# How to align Kendo Tab Strip tabs on the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo Tab Strip for the first time and I have a simple tab strip with two tabs. I want to allign them on the right side of the tab strip. How would I accomplish this?

My mark-up:

```
<div id="tabStrip" class="assignment-portal-tab-strip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">
            Provider Contacts
        </li>
        <li>
            Vendor Contacts
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-container">
```

... Stuff on tab
                
                
... Stuff on tab

My Java Script:

```
$("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: { 
        close: {
        effects: "fadeOut"
        },
        open: {
        effects: "fadeIn"
        }
    }
});
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via CSS:

```
#tabStrip ul {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/itumop/1/edit